# Localhost Error.Its showing Zend framework page

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, xampp

I have installed xampp server on my system working localhost. after that Install zend skeleton application on my system.its Working show demo page.after I want create when I open localhost its showing Zend framework page not show localhost phpmyadmin page? help me.......

Comment: if you have add anything to your local vhost file check that again or remove

Answer (score 1):

1) in order to make phpmyadmin work with ZendServer you have to install it as an application (see [here](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6/content/installing_phpmyadmin.htm))

If you want further info please detail a little bit better which page you are trying to access (localhost, localhost/phpmyadmin, localhost:10081/ZendServer) and which result you get.

cheers,
romeo